Argument type BN is assignable to parameter of type u64
I tried to create a test for the vote app I am following in the Solana Bootcamp but in the test file I got an error when initializing the poll. Here are my files
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("coUnmi3oBUtwtd9fjeAvSsJssXh5A5xyPbhpewyzRVF");

#[program]
pub mod voting {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_poll(ctx: Context<InitializePoll>,
                            poll_id: u64,
                            description: String,
                            poll_start: u64,
                            poll_end: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let poll = &mut ctx.accounts.poll;
        poll.poll_id = poll_id;
        poll.description = description;
        poll.poll_start = poll_start,
        poll.poll_end = poll_end;
        poll.candidate_votes = 0;

        Ok(())
    }

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    #[instruction(poll_id: u64)]
    pub struct InitializePoll<'info> {
        #[account(mut)]
        pub signer: Signer<'info>,
        #[account(
            init,
            payer = signer,
            space = 8 + Poll::INIT_SPACE,
            seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
            bump,
        )]
        pub poll: Account<'info, Poll>,

        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    }

    #[account]
    #[derive(InitSpace)]
    pub struct Poll {
        pub poll_id: u64,
        #[max_len(280)]
        pub description: String,
        pub poll_start: u64,
        pub poll_end: u64,
        pub candidate_votes: u64,
    }
}

test file
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { BankrunProvider, startAnchor } from 'anchor-bankrun';
import {Program} from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import {Keypair, PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js';
import {Voting} from '../target/types/voting';

const IDL = require('../target/idl/voting.json');
const votingAddress = new PublicKey('coUnmi3oBUtwtd9fjeAvSsJssXh5A5xyPbhpewyzRVF');

describe('voting', () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  it('Initialize Voting', async () => {
    const context = await startAnchor("", [{name: "voting", programId: votingAddress}], []);
      const provider = new BankrunProvider(context);

    const votingProgram = new Program<Voting>(
      IDL,
      provider
    );

    const votingKeypair = Keypair.generate();

    await votingProgram.methods.initializePoll(
      new anchor.BN(1),
      "What is your favorite sandwish?",
      new anchor.BN(0),
      new anchor.BN(1835048538),
    ).rpc();
  })

})

The error is from this line of code
await votingProgram.methods.initializePoll(
      new anchor.BN(1),
      "What is your favorite sandwish?",
      new anchor.BN(0),
      new anchor.BN(1835048538),
    ).rpc();

Error code
Argument of type '[BN, string, BN, BN]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArgsTuple<[{ name: "pollId"; type: "u64"; }], RecursiveDepth4<[{ name: "poll"; type: { kind: "struct"; fields: [{ name: "pollId"; type: "u64"; }, { name: "description"; type: "string"; }, { name: "pollStart"; type: "u64"; }, { ...; }, { ...; }]; }; }], DecodedHelper<...>>>'.
  Type '[BN, string, BN, BN]' is not assignable to type '[BN]'.
    Source has 4 element(s) but target allows only 1.ts(2345)

